# how to change existing parameter in javascript constructor function

Tags: javascript

```
function car(model,seat_capacity){

    return {
        model:model,
        seat_capacity:seat_capacity,


        print:function(){
            return "Model ="+ this.model + ", Seat Capacity =" +this.seat_capacity
        }
    }
}
```

How to increment the seat_capacity of all object by 10?

Comment: Btw, this is called a factory function not a constructor function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add 10 to the seat capacity, you could change the constructor like this slightly.

```
function car(m,s){
return {
  model : m,
  seat_capacity : s + 10;
  print : function (){......}
  }
}
```

And if you are taking about increasing the capacity later, you can access the property of the object

```
let c = new car("someModel", 5);
c.seat_capacity += 10;
```

Comment: OP wants to increase the capacity of **all** instances.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a property `increase` on the `Car` object, default it to `0` and use it to calculate `seat_capacity` accessing `this.seat_cpacity` using a `getter`:

```js
function Car(model, seat_capacity) {
  Car.increase = 0;
  return {
    model: model,
    get seat_capacity() { return seat_capacity + Car.increase; },
    print: function() {
      return "Model =" + this.model + ", Seat Capacity =" + this.seat_capacity
    },
  }
}

let a = new Car("Ford Mustang", 4);
let b = new Car("Porsche 911", 2);
console.log(a.print(), b.print()); // 4, 2

Car.increase = 10;
console.log(a.print(), b.print()); // 14, 12
```